# Amazon Forecast boto3 waiter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, botocore

I'm writing a boto3 waiter for Amazon Forecast. Specifically for the dataset import jobs. I'm using the DescribeDataset operation for this purpose. The idea is to wait until the import jobs are active to create a predictor, either in the same Lambda function or another.

DescribeDataset reference
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/forecast.html#ForecastService.Client.describe_dataset

Choice of argument/expected in acceptors

```
Status (string) --
The status of the dataset. States include:
ACTIVE
CREATE_PENDING , CREATE_IN_PROGRESS , CREATE_FAILED
DELETE_PENDING , DELETE_IN_PROGRESS , DELETE_FAILED
UPDATE_PENDING , UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS , UPDATE_FAILED
The UPDATE states apply while data is imported to the dataset from a call to the CreateDatasetImportJob operation and reflect the status of the dataset import job. For example, when the import job status is CREATE_IN_PROGRESS, the status of the dataset is UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS.
```

I used the following link as a guide to configuring the waiter.
https://www.2ndwatch.com/blog/use-waiters-boto3-write/

It seems straightforward but there isn't much to go on when creating a waiter. I'm pretty new to boto3 and Lambda. Am I making simple errors, leaving something out, or misunderstanding how waiters work?

Any help is appreciated.

The DatasetArn parameter is correct for waiter.wait()

I'm receiving the following error after testing the code below in Lambda. I manually run the test shortly after the target and related import jobs begin. Execution succeeds after the import jobs are active.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2020-06-15T15:13:21.144Z a9c5019d-94c8-4332-863e-3bac2a6c8b7f Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}
```

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import WaiterError
from botocore.waiter import WaiterModel
from botocore.waiter import create_waiter_with_client

forecast = boto3.client('forecast')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    delay = 10
    max_attempts = 15

    waiter_name = 'TargetImportJobStatus'
    waiter_config = {
        'version': 2,
        'waiters': {
            'TargetImportJobStatus': {
                'operation': 'DescribeDataset',
                'delay': delay,
                'maxAttempts': max_attempts,
                'acceptors': [
                    {
                        'matcher': 'path',
                        'expected': 'ACTIVE',
                        'argument': 'Status',
                        'state': 'success'
                    },
                    {
                        'matcher': 'path',
                        'expected': 'UPDATE_PENDING',
                        'argument': 'Status',
                        'state': 'retry'

                    },
                    {
                        'matcher': 'path',
                        'expected': 'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS',
                        'argument': "Status",
                        'state': 'retry'
                    },
                    {
                        'matcher': 'path',
                        'expected': 'UPDATE_FAILED',
                        'argument': 'Status',
                        'state': 'failure'
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    }

    waiter_model = WaiterModel(waiter_config)
    custom_waiter = create_waiter_with_client(waiter_name, waiter_model, forecast)    

    try:
        custom_waiter.wait(
            DatasetArn=target_dataset_arn
        )


    except WaiterError as e:
        print(e)

    w_name = 'RelatedImportJobStatus'
    w_config = {
        'version': 2,
        'waiters': {
            'RelatedImportJobStatus': {
                'operation': 'DescribeDataset',
                'delay': delay,
                'maxAttempts': max_attempts,
                'acceptors': [
                    {
                        'matcher': 'path',
                        'expected': 'ACTIVE',
                        'argument': 'Status',
                        'state': 'success'
                    },
                    {
                        'matcher': 'path',
                        'expected': 'UPDATE_PENDING',
                        'argument': 'Status',
                        'state': 'retry'

                    },
                    {
                        'matcher': 'path',
                        'expected': 'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS',
                        'argument': 'Status',
                        'state': 'retry'
                    },
                    {
                        'matcher': 'path',
                        'expected': 'UPDATE_FAILED',
                        'argument': 'Status',
                        'state': 'failure'
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    }

    w_model = WaiterModel(waiter_config)
    w_waiter = create_waiter_with_client(waiter_name, waiter_model, forecast)    

    try:
        w_waiter.wait(
            DatasetArn=related_dataset_arn
        )


    except WaiterError as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Timeout changed to 15 minutes, delay=30, max_attempts=30